# Entity Framework: turning lazy loading off

Tags: entity-framework, lazy-loading

I have the following piece of code which loads the entities in a lazy mode, I tried to set the lazy loading to false by adding this line of code

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

to the top of the function to see what will happen and I expected an exception to be thrown but no thing happened and the code executed normally so could any one explains me what happens when I turn lazy loading off.

```
public List<Report> GetReportsByRole(int numberOfRecords, int pageNumber)
{
    if (CurrentUser.Role == 3)
    {
        return context.Reports.Where(report => report.ReportCreator.DepartmentOfTheUser.Company == CurrentUser.Company).OrderByDescending(report => report.Date).Skip(pageNumber * numberOfRecords).Take(numberOfRecords).ToList();
    }
    else
        if (CurrentUser.Role == 2)
        {
            return context.Reports.Where(report => report.ReportCreator.Depratment == CurrentUser.Department).OrderByDescending(report => report.Date).Skip(pageNumber * numberOfRecords).Take(numberOfRecords).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return context.Reports.Where(report => report.CreatedBy == CurrentUser.Id).OrderByDescending(report => report.Date).Skip(pageNumber * numberOfRecords).Take(numberOfRecords).ToList();
        }
}
```

Comment: If you were to access a navigation-property (for example, `ReportCreator`) of one of the `Report`s returned from your method, you'll notice it's `null`

Comment: Lazy loading is not a feature that takes place at the time you execute a query. It takes place once you have materialized your query and you try to consult some navigation property from one of the returned entities.

Comment: @haim770 and octavioccl thanks for your comments, now I understand what happens

Comment: If you use eager operators, like ToList, there is no lazy loading. Then... If you want it to bring back some object related to the object you are querying, you should use .Include( o => o.PropertyName ) in your query. I usually place it before the Where.